# Import data into Excel file from a working file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a long code for web scraping data into an interim working file and then generating an Excel file where this data will be imported in. I want to split the code into two parts, so that I don't have to run the webscraping every single time if my working file is already created.

How do I reference the working file ("data") in the second part of the code that generates the Excel file?

My current line of code resulted in vanishing all the data from the existing working file:

```
data=eval(open('data','r',encoding='utf8').read())
```

Should it be simply this?

```
data=open('data','r',encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: perhaps add which libraries you are using..

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` here at all? _Please_ don't use that function when it isn't necessary. This is a huge security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You may try reading the excel file as the very first step as a DataFrame into your script. If the file exists and it's empty, it will return an empty dataframe and if it doesn't exist you write a simple code to create an empty one. In any case you create a starting dataframe for yourself. After extracting your required data, you simply append your result to your initial dataframe and overwrite the Excel file with your final dataframe. In order to speed the two processes up and to save time, you may use a multi threading programme to the first part of the task where you create the initial dataframe while the second part of your programme scrapes the data.

If this doesn't answer your question, do let me know what is it that you
Were looking for exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I do have both files already. Perhaps I was not clear: I have a database (working file that contains all my data already) and I have created an empty Excel, and I do have a code to copy the data from database into this Excel, but it works only in the long thread of code that includes webscapping.

I want to add an extra line that will reference this database file without running the web scrapping part. I want to execute the part where I create Excel file and write data into it standalone.

Comment: Ohh, you can simple create both parts as separate functions and run a multithread on that. what this will do is run both your functions (that is copy data from your database to your excel and run web scraping) paralelly. You may want to refer to multiprocessing library for this

Comment: I believe the issue is not on how to create a separate functions, but how to define the working file in the second part of the code. What I mean is that my later code has a lot of:

```
excelFile.cell(rowNum,#).value=data[itemNum]["ColumnName"]
```

Comment: So I using "data" in the code later, but it is not defined and using the open function resulted in deleting all data from Excel. Simply using data="file location\data" resulted in error too

Comment: Can you share your entire code once? You may include dummy data values in case the data is sensitive